# ActiveRelation where statement on child attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a has_one condition that I'm trying to access but am having a little trouble

```
Solicitation belongs_to :lead
Lead has_many :solicitations
```

My first statement grabs all solicitations for a user

```
@solicitations = current_user.solicitations.includes(:lead)
```

I can already access the attribute lead.case_type and could just cycle through the relation and put them in their places manually, but I figure their is an easier way.

What I am trying to do is something similar to

```
@solicitations.where("lead.case_type = ?", "Civil")
```

I have tried these and receive an unknown column error lead.case_type

```
Solicitation.all(:conditions => {:lead => {:case_type => 'Civil'}}, :joins => :lead)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `lead.case_type`, but (if you're following Rails' conventions) your table name is `leads`. This should work:

```
@solicitations = current_user.solicitations.includes(:lead).where("leads.case_type = ?", "Civil")
```

You could also use [`joins`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables) for that:

```
@solicitations = current_user.solicitations.joins(:lead).where("leads.case_type = ?", "Civil")
```

`includes` does an outer join, whereas `joins` does an inner join. Since you're querying the joined table an inner join would be better here.

In `where` you always have to use the table name (plural), but in `includes` and `joins` it depends on the relationship. In this case `solicitation` belongs to `lead`, so you have to use `:lead` (singular). It's a bit confusing, but I hope this clears it up for you.

Comment: Both of those worked, thank you so much for the help on the syntax and explanation of the join vs. include!